# Dynamically extensible threadpool implementation in C

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety, concurrency, pthreads

## Purpose

For my recent project, I needed a thread pool. I saw a lot of implementations at GitHub, but most of them were quite complicated. With complication comes performance penalty. Most importantly, none of them provided dynamically managable threads. So I decided to write myself a thread pool in C. It was a fun project to make anyway.

## Discussion

1. My `ThreadPool` contains two queues, one thread queue(`ThreadList *`) and one job queue(`Job *`). As usual, new jobs end up in the rear of the job queue. The job queue is protected by a `queuemutex`, and all access and modifications are made to the queue only after holding the mutex.
2. The thread queue, or most notably the `numThreads`, the thread counter, is guarded by the another mutex and conditional, namely `condmutex` and `conditional`, which serves the purpose of conditional idle wait of the threads. When a new thread is added to the queue, `condmutex` is held, `numThread` is incremented, and the lock is released. Then only the actual `pthread_create` call is issued, and a new `ThreadList *` is added to the thread queue.
3. When a thread wants to go in idle state, either because job queue is `NULL` or a `suspendPool` call is issued, it holds the `condmutex` first, then increments `waitingThreads`, which is a counter for waiting threads. It then checks if all threads are waiting and it is not a suspension call, if it's true, it signals `endconditional`, and breaks any potential caller waiting in the `waitForComplete` call. It then goes into `conditional` wait, and when wakes up, decrements the `waitingThreads` and releases `condmutex`.
4. When a thread is intended to be removed from the pool, `removeThreadFromPool` is issued. This method just holds the `queuemutex`, increments `removeThreads` counter, and returns. In the execution loop in `threadExecutor`, each thread first holds the `queuemutex`, then checks if `removeThreads` is positive. If it is, the thread `break`s from the loop. When a thread comes outside of the execution loop, it checks if the pool is still running or not, indicated by the flag `run` in `ThreadPool`. If the pool is running but the thread is still outside of the loop, it sure was a removal call, in which case, the thread releases the `queuemutex`, and exits.
5. `suspendPool` and `resumePool` works in a similar flag based manner, with the flag `suspend` and using the mutexes `queuemutex` and `condmutex`. As no thread is actively suspended while executing, only any thread wanting to get a job from the queue by holding the `queuemutex` is blocked, and put to suspend using step 3. Since all idle threads are idle holding `condmutex` and `conditional`, `resumePool` resets the flag and `broadcast`s for the `conditional`.
6. The `waitToComplete` call waits on `endconditional`, which is signaled by any thread whenever `waitingThreads==numThreads` and `suspend==0`.

## Implementation

#### Header : mythreads.h

```
#ifndef MYTHREADS_H
#define MYTHREADS_H

/* The main pool structure
 * 
 * To find member descriptions, see mythreads.c .
 */
typedef struct ThreadPool ThreadPool;

/* The status enum to indicate any failure.
 * 
 * These values can be compared to all the functions
 * that returns an integer, to findout the status of
 * the execution of the function.
 */
typedef enum Status{
    MEMORY_UNAVAILABLE,
    QUEUE_LOCK_FAILED,
    QUEUE_UNLOCK_FAILED,
    SIGNALLING_FAILED,
    BROADCASTING_FAILED,
    COND_WAIT_FAILED,
    POOL_NOT_INITIALIZED,
    POOL_STOPPED,
    INVALID_NUMBER,
    COMPLETED   
} Status;

/* Creates a new thread pool with argument number of threads. 
 * 
 * When this method returns, and if the return value is not 
 * NULL, it is assured that all threads are initialized and 
 * in waiting state. If any thread fails to initialize, 
 * typically if the pthread_create method fails, a warning 
 * message is print on the stdout. This method also can fail
 * in case of insufficient memory, which is rare, and a NULL
 * is returned in that case.
 */
ThreadPool * createPool(unsigned int);

/* Waits till all the threads in the pool are finished.
 *
 * When this method returns, it is assured that all threads
 * in the pool have finished executing, and in waiting state.
 */
void waitToComplete(ThreadPool *);

/* Destroys the argument pool.
 *
 * This method tries to stop all threads in the pool
 * immediately, and destroys any resource that the pool has
 * used in its lifetime. However, this method will not
 * return until all threads have finished processing their
 * present work. That is, this method will not halt any
 * actively executing thread. Rather, it'll wait for the
 * present jobs to complete, and will keep the threads from
 * running any new jobs. This method then joins all the
 * threads, destroys all synchronization objects, and frees
 * any remaining jobs, finally freeing the pool itself.
 */
void destroyPool(ThreadPool *);

/* Add a new job to the pool.
 *
 * This method adds a new job, that is a worker function,
 * to the pool. The execution of the function is performed
 * asynchronously, however. This method only assures the
 * addition of the job to the job queue. The job queue is
 * ordered in FIFO style, i.e., for this job to execute,
 * all the jobs that has been added previously has to be
 * executed first. This method doesn't guarantee the thread
 * on which the job may execute. Rather, when its turn comes,
 * the thread which first becomes idle, executes this job.
 * When all threads are idle, any one of them wakes up and
 * executes this function asynchronously.
 */
int addJobToPool(ThreadPool *, void (*func)(void *), void *);

/* Add some new threads to the pool.
 * 
 * This function adds specified number of new threads to the 
 * argument threadpool. When this function returns, it is 
 * ensured that a new thread has been added to the pool. 
 * However, this new thread will only come to effect if there 
 * are remainder jobs, that is the job queue is not presently 
 * empty. This new thread will not steal any running jobs 
 * from the running threads. Occasionally, this method will 
 * return some error codes, typically due to the failure of 
 * pthread_create, or for insufficient memory. These error 
 * codes can be compared using the Status enum above.
 */
int addThreadsToPool(ThreadPool *, int);

/* Suspend all currently executing threads in the pool.
 *
 * This method pauses all currently executing threads in
 * the pool. When the method call returns, it is guaranteed
 * that all threads have been suspended at appropiate
 * breakpoints. However, if a thread is presently executing,
 * it is not forcefully suspended. Rather, the call waits
 * till the thread completes the present job, and then
 * halts the thread.
 */
void suspendPool(ThreadPool *);

/* Resume a suspended pool.
 *
 * This method resumes a pool, aynchronously, if and only 
 * if the pool was suspended before. When the method returns,
 * it is guaranteed the all the threads of the pool will
 * wake up from suspend very soon in future. This method 
 * fails if the pool was not previously suspended.
 */
void resumePool(ThreadPool *);

/* Remove an existing thread from the pool.
 *
 * This function will remove one thread from the threadpool,
 * asynchronously. That is, this method will not stop any
 * active threads, rather it'll merely indicate the wish.
 * When any active thread will become idle, before becoming
 * active again the thread will check if removal is wished.
 * If it is wished, then thread will immediately exit. This
 * method can run N times to remove N threads, however it
 * has some serious consequences. If N is greater than the
 * number of threads present in the pool, say M, then all
 * M threads will be stopped. However, next (N-M) threads
 * will also immediately exit when added to the pool. If
 * all M threads are removed from the queue, then the job
 * queue will halt, and when a new thread will be added to
 * the pool, the queue will automatically resume from the
 * position where it stopped.
 */
void removeThreadFromPool(ThreadPool *);

#endif
```

#### Library : mythreads.c

**Structure definitions**

```
/* A singly linked list of threads. This list
 * gives tremendous flexibility managing the 
 * threads at runtime.
 */
typedef struct ThreadList {
    pthread_t thread; // The thread object
    struct ThreadList *next; // Link to next thread
} ThreadList;

/* A singly linked list of worker functions. This
 * list is implemented as a queue to manage the
 * execution in the pool.
 */
typedef struct Job {
    void (*function)(void *); // The worker function
    void *args; // Argument to the function
    struct Job *next; // Link to next Job
} Job;

/* The core pool structure. This is the only
 * user accessible structure in the API. It contains
 * all the primitives necessary to provide
 * synchronization between the threads, along with
 * dynamic management and execution control.
 */
struct ThreadPool {
    /* The FRONT of the thread queue in the pool.
     * It typically points to the first thread
     * created in the pool.
     */
    ThreadList * threads;

    /* The REAR of the thread queue in the pool.
     * Points to the last, and most young thread
     * added to the pool.
     */
    ThreadList * rearThreads;

    /* Number of threads in the pool. As this can
     * grow dynamically, access and modification 
     * of it is bounded by a mutex.
     */
    unsigned int numThreads;

    /* The indicator which indicates the number
     * of threads to remove. If this is equal to
     * N, then N threads will be removed from the
     * pool when they are idle. All threads
     * typically check the value of this variable
     * before executing a job, and if finds the 
     * value >0, immediately exits.
     */
    unsigned int removeThreads;

    /* Denotes the number of idle threads in the
     * pool at any given instant of time. This value
     * is used to check if all threads are idle,
     * and thus triggering the end of job queue or
     * the initialization of the pool, whichever
     * applicable.
     */
    volatile unsigned int waitingThreads;

    /* Denotes whether the pool is presently
     * initalized or not. This variable is used to
     * busy wait after the creation of the pool
     * to ensure all threads are in waiting state.
     */
    volatile unsigned short isInitialized;

    /* The main mutex for the job queue. All
     * operations on the queue is done after locking
     * this mutex to ensure consistency.
     */
    pthread_mutex_t queuemutex;

    /* This mutex indicates whether a thread is
     * presently in idle state or not, and is used
     * in conjunction with the conditional below.
     */
    pthread_mutex_t condmutex;

    /* Conditional to ensure conditional wait.
     * When idle, each thread waits on this 
     * conditional, which is signaled by various
     * methods to indicate the wake of the thread.
     */
    pthread_cond_t conditional;

    /* Ensures pool state. When the pool is running,
     * this is set to 1. All the threads loop on
     * this condition, and exits immediately when
     * it is set to 0, which happens when the pool
     * is destroyed.
     */
    _Atomic unsigned short run;

    /* Used to assign unique thread IDs to each
     * running threads. It is an always incremental
     * counter.
     */
    unsigned int threadID;

    /* The FRONT of the job queue, which typically
     * points to the job to be executed next.
     */
    Job *FRONT;

    /* The REAR of the job queue, which points
     * to the job last added in the pool.
     */
    Job *REAR;

    /* Mutex used to denote the end of the job
     * queue, which triggers the function
     * waitForComplete.
     */
    pthread_mutex_t endmutex;

    /* Conditional to signal the end of the job
     * queue.
     */
    pthread_cond_t endconditional;

    /* Variable to impose and withdraw
     * the suspend state.
     */
    unsigned short suspend;
};
```

**1. Core executor function**

```
static void *threadExecutor(void *pl){
    ThreadPool *pool = (ThreadPool *)pl; // Get the pool
    pthread_mutex_lock(&pool->queuemutex); // Lock the mutex
    unsigned int id = ++pool->threadID; // Get an id
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&pool->queuemutex); // Release the mutex

#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("\n[THREADPOOL:THREAD%u:INFO] Starting execution loop!", id);
#endif
    //Start the core execution loop
    while(pool->run){ // run==1, we should get going
#ifdef DEBUG
        printf("\n[THREADPOOL:THREAD%u:INFO] Trying to lock the mutex!", id);
#endif

        pthread_mutex_lock(&pool->queuemutex); //Lock the queue mutex

        if(pool->removeThreads>0){ // A thread is needed to be removed
#ifdef DEBUG
            printf("\n[THREADPOOL:THREAD%u:INFO] Removal signalled! Exiting the execution loop!", id);
#endif
            pthread_mutex_lock(&pool->condmutex);
            pool->waitingThreads++; // Register as forever waiting thread
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&pool->condmutex);
            break; // Exit the loop
        }
        Job *presentJob = pool->FRONT; // Get the first job
        if(presentJob==NULL || pool->suspend){ // Queue is empty!

#ifdef DEBUG
            if(presentJob==NULL)
                printf("\n[THREADPOOL:THREAD%u:INFO] Queue is empty! Unlocking the mutex!", id);
            else
                printf("\n[THREADPOOL:THREAD%u:INFO] Suspending thread!", id);
#endif
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&pool->queuemutex); // Unlock the mutex

            pthread_mutex_lock(&pool->condmutex); // Hold the conditional mutex
            pool->waitingThreads++; // Add yourself as a waiting thread
#ifdef DEBUG
            printf("\n[THREADPOOL:THREAD%u:INFO] Waiting threads %u!", id, pool->waitingThreads);
#endif
            if(!pool->suspend && pool->waitingThreads==pool->numThreads){ // All threads are idle
#ifdef DEBUG
                printf("\n[THREADPOOL:THREAD%u:INFO] All threads are idle now!", id);
#endif
                if(pool->isInitialized){ // Pool is initialized, time to trigger the end conditional
#ifdef DEBUG
                    printf("\n[THREADPOOL:THREAD%u:INFO] Signaling endconditional!" ,id);
                    fflush(stdout);
#endif
                    pthread_mutex_lock(&pool->endmutex); // Lock the mutex
                    pthread_cond_signal(&pool->endconditional); // Signal the end
                    pthread_mutex_unlock(&pool->endmutex); // Release the mutex
#ifdef DEBUG
                    printf("\n[THREADPOOL:THREAD%u:INFO] Signalled any monitor!", id);
#endif
                }
                else // We are initializing the pool
                    pool->isInitialized = 1; // Break the busy wait
            }



#ifdef DEBUG
            printf("\n[THREADPOOL:THREAD%u:INFO] Going to conditional wait!", id);
            fflush(stdout);
#endif
            pthread_cond_wait(&pool->conditional, &pool->condmutex); // Idle wait on conditional

            /* Woke up! */

            if(pool->waitingThreads>0) // Unregister youself as a waiting thread
                pool->waitingThreads--;

            pthread_mutex_unlock(&pool->condmutex); // Woke up! Release the mutex

#ifdef DEBUG
            printf("\n[THREADPOOL:THREAD%u:INFO] Woke up from conditional wait!", id);
#endif          
        }
        else{ // There is a job in the pool

            pool->FRONT = pool->FRONT->next; // Shift FRONT to right
            if(pool->FRONT==NULL) // No jobs next
                pool->REAR = NULL; // Reset the REAR
#ifdef DEBUG
            else
                printQueue(pool->FRONT);

            printf("\n[THREADPOOL:THREAD%u:INFO] Job recieved! Unlocking the mutex!", id);
#endif
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&pool->queuemutex); // Unlock the mutex

#ifdef DEBUG
            printf("\n[THREADPOOL:THREAD%u:INFO] Executing the job now!", id);
#endif

            presentJob->function(presentJob->args); // Execute the job

#ifdef DEBUG
            printf("\n[THREADPOOL:THREAD%u:INFO] Job completed! Releasing memory for the job!", id);
#endif

            free(presentJob); // Release memory for the job
        }
    }


    if(pool->run){ // We exited, but the pool is running! It must be force removal!
#ifdef DEBUG
        printf("\n[THREADPOOL:THREAD%u:INFO] Releasing the lock!", id);
#endif
        pool->removeThreads--; // Alright, I'm shutting now
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&pool->queuemutex); // We broke the loop, release the mutex now
#ifdef DEBUG
        printf("\n[THREADPOOL:THREAD%u:INFO] Stopping now..", id);
#endif
    }
#ifdef DEBUG
    else // The pool is stopped
        printf("\n[THREADPOOL:THREAD%u:INFO] Pool has been stopped! Exiting now..", id);
#endif

    pthread_exit((void *)COMPLETED); // Exit
}
```

**2. Create pool**

```
ThreadPool * createPool(unsigned int numThreads){
    ThreadPool * pool = (ThreadPool *)malloc(sizeof(ThreadPool)); // Allocate memory for the pool
    if(pool==NULL){ // Oops!
        printf("[THREADPOOL:INIT:ERROR] Unable to allocate memory for the pool!");
        return NULL;
    }

#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("\n[THREADPOOL:INIT:INFO] Allocated %lu bytes for new pool!", sizeof(ThreadPool));
#endif
    // Initialize members with default values
    pool->numThreads = 0; 
    pool->FRONT = NULL;
    pool->REAR = NULL;
    pool->waitingThreads = 0;
    pool->isInitialized = 0;
    pool->removeThreads = 0;
    pool->suspend = 0;

#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("\n[THREADPOOL:INIT:INFO] Initializing mutexes!");
#endif

    pthread_mutex_init(&pool->queuemutex, NULL); // Initialize queue mutex
    pthread_mutex_init(&pool->condmutex, NULL); // Initialize idle mutex
    pthread_mutex_init(&pool->endmutex, NULL); // Initialize end mutex

#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("\n[THREADPOOL:INIT:INFO] Initiliazing conditionals!");
#endif

    pthread_cond_init(&pool->endconditional, NULL); // Initialize end conditional
    pthread_cond_init(&pool->conditional, NULL); // Initialize idle conditional

    pool->run = 1; // Start the pool

#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("\n[THREADPOOL:INIT:INFO] Successfully initialized all members of the pool!");
    printf("\n[THREADPOOL:INIT:INFO] Initializing %u threads..",numThreads);
#endif

    addThreadsToPool(pool, numThreads); // Add threads to the pool

#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("\n[THREADPOOL:INIT:INFO] Waiting for all threads to start..");
#endif

    while(!pool->isInitialized); // Busy wait till the pool is initialized

#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("\n[THREADPOOL:INIT:INFO] New threadpool initialized successfully!");
#endif

    return pool;
}
```

**3. Add threads**

```
int addThreadsToPool(ThreadPool *pool, int threads){
    if(pool==NULL){ // Sanity check
        printf("\n[THREADPOOL:ADD:ERROR] Pool is not initialized!");
        return POOL_NOT_INITIALIZED;
    }
    if(!pool->run){
        printf("\n[THREADPOOL:ADD:ERROR] Pool already stopped!");
        return POOL_STOPPED;
    }
    if(threads<1){
        printf("\n[THREADPOOL:ADD:WARNING] Tried to add invalid number of threads %d!", threads);
        return INVALID_NUMBER;
    }

    int rc = 0;
#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("\n[THREADPOOL:ADD:INFO] Holding the condmutex..");
#endif
    pthread_mutex_lock(&pool->condmutex);
    pool->numThreads += threads; // Increment the thread count to prevent idle signal
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&pool->condmutex);
#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("\n[THREADPOOL:ADD:INFO] Speculative increment done!");
#endif
    int i = 0;
    for(i=0;i<threads;i++){

        ThreadList *newThread = (ThreadList *)malloc(sizeof(ThreadList)); // Allocate a new thread
        newThread->next = NULL;
        rc = pthread_create(&newThread->thread, NULL, threadExecutor, (void *)pool); // Start the thread
        if(rc){
            printf("\n[THREADPOOL:ADD:ERROR] Unable to create thread %d(error code %d)!", (i+1), rc);
            pthread_mutex_lock(&pool->condmutex);
            pool->numThreads--;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&pool->condmutex);
        }
        else{
#ifdef DEBUG
            printf("\n[THREADPOOL:ADD:INFO] Initialized thread %u!", (i+1));
#endif
            if(pool->rearThreads==NULL) // This is the first thread
                pool->threads = pool->rearThreads = newThread;
            else // There are threads in the pool
                pool->rearThreads->next = newThread;
            pool->rearThreads = newThread; // This is definitely the last thread
        }
    }
    return rc;
}
```

**4. Remove thread**

```
void removeThreadFromPool(ThreadPool *pool){
    if(pool==NULL || !pool->isInitialized){
        printf("\n[THREADPOOL:REM:ERROR] Pool is not initialized!");
        return;
    }
    if(!pool->run){
        printf("\n[THREADPOOL:REM:WARNING] Removing thread from a stopped pool!");
        return;
    }

#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("\n[THREADPOOL:REM:INFO] Acquiring the lock!");
#endif
    pthread_mutex_lock(&pool->queuemutex); // Lock the mutex
#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("\n[THREADPOOL:REM:INFO] Incrementing the removal count");
#endif
    pool->removeThreads++; // Indicate the willingness of removal
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&pool->queuemutex); // Unlock the mutex
#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("\n[THREADPOOL:REM:INFO] Waking up any sleeping threads!");
#endif
    pthread_mutex_lock(&pool->condmutex); // Lock the wait mutex
    pthread_cond_signal(&pool->conditional); // Signal any idle threads
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&pool->condmutex); // Release the wait mutex
#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("\n[THREADPOOL:REM:INFO] Signalling complete!");
#endif
}
```

**5. Add job**

```
int addJobToPool(ThreadPool *pool, void (*func)(void *args), void *args){
    if(pool==NULL || !pool->isInitialized){ // Sanity check
        printf("\n[THREADPOOL:EXEC:ERROR] Pool is not initialized!");
        return POOL_NOT_INITIALIZED;
    }
    if(!pool->run){
        printf("\n[THREADPOOL:EXEC:ERROR] Trying to add a job in a stopped pool!");
        return POOL_STOPPED;
    }

    Job *newJob = (Job *)malloc(sizeof(Job)); // Allocate memory
    if(newJob==NULL){ // Who uses 2KB RAM nowadays?
        printf("\n[THREADPOOL:EXEC:ERROR] Unable to allocate memory for new job!");
        return MEMORY_UNAVAILABLE;
    }

#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("\n[THREADPOOL:EXEC:INFO] Allocated %lu bytes for new job!", sizeof(Job));
#endif

    newJob->function = func; // Initialize the function
    newJob->args = args; // Initialize the argument
    newJob->next = NULL; // Reset the link

#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("\n[THREADPOOL:EXEC:INFO] Locking the queue for insertion of the job!");
#endif

    pthread_mutex_lock(&pool->queuemutex); // Inserting the job, lock the queue

    if(pool->FRONT==NULL) // This is the first job
        pool->FRONT = pool->REAR = newJob;
    else // There are other jobs
        pool->REAR->next = newJob;
    pool->REAR = newJob; // This is the last job

#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("\n[THREADPOOL:EXEC:INFO] Inserted the job at the end of the queue!");
#endif

    if(pool->waitingThreads>0){ // There are some threads sleeping, wake'em up
#ifdef DEBUG
        printf("\n[THREADPOOL:EXEC:INFO] Signaling any idle thread!");
#endif
        pthread_mutex_lock(&pool->condmutex); // Lock the mutex
        pthread_cond_signal(&pool->conditional); // Signal the conditional
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&pool->condmutex); // Release the mutex

#ifdef DEBUG
        printf("\n[THREADPOOL:EXEC:INFO] Signaling successful!");
#endif
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&pool->queuemutex); // Finally, release the queue

#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("\n[THREADPOOL:EXEC:INFO] Unlocked the mutex!");
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

**6. Wait for completion**

```
void waitToComplete(ThreadPool *pool){
    if(pool==NULL || !pool->isInitialized){ // Sanity check
        printf("\n[THREADPOOL:WAIT:ERROR] Pool is not initialized!");
        return;
    }
    if(!pool->run){
        printf("\n[THREADPOOL:WAIT:ERROR] Pool already stopped!");
        return;
    }

    pthread_mutex_lock(&pool->condmutex);
    if(pool->numThreads==pool->waitingThreads){
#ifdef DEBUG
        printf("\n[THREADPOOL:WAIT:INFO] All threads are already idle!");
#endif
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&pool->condmutex);
        return;
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&pool->condmutex);
#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("\n[THREADPOOL:WAIT:INFO] Waiting for all threads to become idle..");
#endif
    pthread_mutex_lock(&pool->endmutex); // Lock the mutex
    pthread_cond_wait(&pool->endconditional, &pool->endmutex); // Wait for end signal
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&pool->endmutex); // Unlock the mutex
#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("\n[THREADPOOL:WAIT:INFO] All threads are idle now!");
#endif
}
```

**7. Suspend pool**

```
void suspendPool(ThreadPool *pool){
    if(pool==NULL || !pool->isInitialized){ // Sanity check
        printf("\n[THREADPOOL:SUSP:ERROR] Pool is not initialized!");
        return;
    }
    if(!pool->run){ // Pool is stopped
        printf("\n[THREADPOOL:SUSP:ERROR] Pool already stopped!");
        return;
    }
    if(pool->suspend){ // Pool is already suspended
        printf("\n[THREADPOOL:SUSP:ERROR] Pool already suspended!");
        return;
    }

#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("\n[THREADPOOL:SUSP:INFO] Initiating suspend..");
#endif
    pthread_mutex_lock(&pool->queuemutex); // Lock the queue
    pool->suspend = 1; // Present the wish for suspension
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&pool->queuemutex); // Release the queue
#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("\n[THREADPOOL:SUSP:INFO] Waiting for all threads to be idle..");
    fflush(stdout);
#endif
    while(pool->waitingThreads<pool->numThreads); // Busy wait till all threads are idle
#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("\n[THREADPOOL:SUSP:INFO] Successfully suspended all threads!");
#endif
}
```

**8. Resume pool**

```
void resumePool(ThreadPool *pool){
    if(pool==NULL || !pool->isInitialized){ // Sanity check
        printf("\n[THREADPOOL:RESM:ERROR] Pool is not initialized!");
        return;
    }
    if(!pool->run){ // Pool stopped
        printf("\n[THREADPOOL:RESM:ERROR] Pool is not running!");
        return;
    }
    if(!pool->suspend){ // Pool is not suspended
        printf("\n[THREADPOOL:RESM:WARNING] Pool is not suspended!");
        return;
    }

#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("\n[THREADPOOL:RESM:INFO] Initiating resume..");
#endif
    pthread_mutex_lock(&pool->condmutex);  // Lock the conditional
    pool->suspend = 0; // Reset the state
#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("\n[THREADPOOL:RESM:INFO] Waking up all threads..");
#endif
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&pool->conditional); // Wake up all threads
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&pool->condmutex); // Release the mutex
#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("\n[THREADPOOL:RESM:INFO] Resume complete!");
#endif
}
```

**9. Destroy pool**

```
void destroyPool(ThreadPool *pool){
    if(pool==NULL || !pool->isInitialized){ // Sanity check
        printf("\n[THREADPOOL:EXIT:ERROR] Pool is not initialized!");
        return;
    }

#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("\n[THREADPOOL:EXIT:INFO] Trying to wakeup all waiting threads..");
#endif
    pool->run = 0; // Stop the pool

    pthread_mutex_lock(&pool->condmutex);
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&pool->conditional); // Wake up all idle threads
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&pool->condmutex);

    int rc;
#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("\n[THREADPOOL:EXIT:INFO] Waiting for all threads to exit..");
#endif

    ThreadList *list = pool->threads, *backup = NULL; // For travsersal

    Status stat;
    void *c = &stat;
    unsigned int i = 0;
    while(list!=NULL){

#ifdef DEBUG
        printf("\n[THREADPOOL:EXIT:INFO] Joining thread %u..", i);
#endif

        rc = pthread_join(list->thread, &c); //  Wait for ith thread to join
        if(rc)
            printf("\n[THREADPOOL:EXIT:WARNING] Unable to join THREAD%u!", i);

#ifdef DEBUG        
        else
            printf("\n[THREADPOOL:EXIT:INFO] THREAD%u joined!", i);
#endif

        backup = list;
        list = list->next; // Continue

#ifdef DEBUG
        printf("\n[THREADPOOL:EXIT:INFO] Releasing memory for THREAD%u..", i);
#endif

        free(backup); // Free ith thread
        i++;
    }

#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("\n[THREADPOOL:EXIT:INFO] Destroying remaining jobs..");
#endif

    // Delete remaining jobs
    while(pool->FRONT!=NULL){
        Job *j = pool->FRONT;
        pool->FRONT = pool->FRONT->next;
        free(j);
    }

#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("\n[THREADPOOL:EXIT:INFO] Destroying conditionals..");
#endif
    rc = pthread_cond_destroy(&pool->conditional); // Destroying idle conditional
    rc = pthread_cond_destroy(&pool->endconditional); // Destroying end conditional
    if(rc)
        printf("\n[THREADPOOL:EXIT:WARNING] Unable to destroy one or more conditionals (error code %d)!", rc);

#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("\n[THREADPOOL:EXIT:INFO] Destroying the mutexes..");
#endif

    rc = pthread_mutex_destroy(&pool->queuemutex); // Destroying queue lock
    rc = pthread_mutex_destroy(&pool->condmutex); // Destroying idle lock
    rc = pthread_mutex_destroy(&pool->endmutex); // Destroying end lock
    if(rc)
        printf("\n[THREADPOOL:EXIT:WARNING] Unable to destroy one or mutexes (error code %d)!", rc);

#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("\n[THREADPOOL:EXIT:INFO] Releasing memory for the pool..");
#endif

    free(pool); // Release the pool
#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("\n[THREADPOOL:EXIT:INFO] Pool destruction completed!");
#endif
}
```

An workable example can be found at [GitHub](https://github.com/iamsubhranil/ThreadPool)!

Answer (score 2):

## Debug output

For each line of debug output you write 3 lines of code. You may also want to write debug output to stderr instead of stdout so you'll be able to isolate debug output from regular output. I suggest defining something like the following in a common header:

```c
#ifdef ENABLE_DEBUG_OUTPUT
# define DEBUG(FMT, ...) fprintf(stderr, FMT, __VA_ARGS__)
#else
# define DEBUG(FMT, ...)
#endif
```

instead of writing

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("stuff and %s\n", "other stuff");
#endif
```

you can now write

```
DEBUG("stuff and %s\n", "other stuff");
```

That output will only happen if you define `ENABLE_DEBUG_OUTPUT`.

## Linebreaks

You always put the linebreak at the beginning of your format string (`printf("\nstuff")`). This may lead to strange output (demonstrated with bash, but it still applies):

```bsh
user@host:~$ printf "\nstuff"

stuffuser@host:~$
```

Always put linebreaks at the end of your format string:

```c
printf("stuff\n");
```

## Struct initialization

Instead of writing

```
// Initialize members with default values
pool->numThreads = 0; 
pool->FRONT = NULL;
pool->REAR = NULL;
pool->waitingThreads = 0;
pool->isInitialized = 0;
pool->removeThreads = 0;
pool->suspend = 0;
```

I'd just write

```
memset(pool, 0, sizeof(*pool));
```

That is both shorter and sure to actually zero the whole structure even if you add fields in the future.

## Suspend/Resume

Are there use cases for you being able to suspend/resume your threadpool? Is it useful for something? If you can't think of a use case then don't include it in your API. The more surface your API exposes the harder it is to maintain backwards compatibility in the future.

## Lots of conds/mutexes

I think you can actually reduce the number of mutexes quite a bit. Just one mutex to lock access to the `ThreadPool` and one condition var to wake up threads should be enough to implement the exact same API you're currently using. Lock the mutex whenever you interact with the `ThreadPool`. Always notify your condition var when a job is added. broadcast on the same condition var when the pool is destroyed.

Pseudocode for function executed in thread:

```
lock(pool->mutex)
while (pool->running) {
  var job = get_next_job(pool->queue);
  if (job is null) {
    // No jobs. Go to sleep.
    wait(pool->cond);
    continue;
  }
  else {
    unlock(pool->mutex);
    execute(job);
    lock(pool->mutex);
  }
}
unlock(pool->mutex)
```

Comment: The `memset()` isn't necessarily the same, on platforms where null pointers aren't stored as all-bits-zero.

Comment: According to pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/stddef.h.html for POSIX systems NULL expands to (void*)0. The non-POSIX compatibility ship has already sailed with the usage of pthreads.

Comment: That's absolutely correct (and that's just standard C), but `0` cast to a pointer isn't necessarily *represented in memory* by a sequence of zero bytes.  Assigning the value `0` to a pointer (or comparing a pointer against `0`) means that compiler does any necessary conversion to/from the platform's null representation.  When you go behind the type system's back, none of that is done for you.

Comment: I stand corrected. Thank you for this insight. Do you agree though that for relatively recent architectures `memset` for struct init is a safe thing to do?

Comment: I'd probably avoid it, and instead copy from a static pre-initialised struct.  It *should* always be safe to `memset()` then overwrite the pointer members.  I've never had to use systems (e.g. 8086) with segmented memory or other non-zero null-pointers (I went straight from 68k and PA-RISC to i386), but I always endeavour not to introduce unnecessary non-portability.  BTW, great review in general - I've voted.  :)

Comment: Careful. `sizeof pool` would be the size of the pointer. `sizeof *pool` is better though. I'll edit it.

Comment: Debug output and line breaks are accepted. This happened because I glued small pieces of the pool by parts, and DEBUG was default then. Struct initialization, based on the following comments by @TobySpeight , doesn't seem to be a good idea, which you already accepted. Suspend/Resume was not a requirement, but rather a fun idea to check the stretch of my implementation. It may be useful in places where one is dealing with multiple thredpools, and switching back and forth on the execution of the jobs based on a specific context. Use of mutexes in the API is really generous I know, which again

Comment: happened because of gluing different pieces together. Although I think I will need at least two mutexes, to provide all of idle conditional wait, end signalling for immediate exit and suspend/resume. One will guard the queue and other will deal with the conditional waits. Good review though, really appreciate it.